# How do I redirect traffic using single Istio1.0 gateway resource?

Tags: istio

Use case: 
I have two services running in on premisses k8s cluster with `Istio 1.0`, namely Kibana with `port: 5601` and `Grafana` with `port:3000`.

Need to route these services using path-based routing. The expectation is, using a single gateway need to access both services using path separation.

Example: http://172.16.22.233:31380/kibana and http://172.16.22.233:31380/grafana

I tried the following configuration, but it's not working.

**gateway.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
`
```

**virtualservice.yaml**

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/kibana"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 5601
        host: kibana
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/grafana"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 3000
        host: grafana
`
```

Can someone suggest configurations for gateway and virtual service resources?

Comment: Your configuration should work. Does this task work for you https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ ?

Comment: yes, the task istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress works fine.

Comment: it looks like a bug in Istio. Can you open an issue here https://github.com/istio/istio/issues?

Comment: @SudhakarAmbati, could you tell us, what do you mean under "it's not working". Is it 404 error, or there is no response, or something else?

Comment: @Artem Golenyaev, When I try to access service using browser getting a blank page.

Comment: @Artem Golenyaev, some time getting HTTP ERROR 404 as well

Answer (score 0):

If you request `http://172.16.22.233:31380/kibana`, your VirtualService will route to kibana, but it will also forward the request path `/kibana`. I'm not sure what that does, but sending a 404 response would be my guess.

If you want to access the root page `/`, you need to add a `rewrite` field in your rule:

  `- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/kibana"
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 5601
        host: kibana`

Comment: tried uri rewrite using root "/", still getting same HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: Could you provide setting of the Service for the Gateway? Also, what address are you trying to reach to access Kibana?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev, To access kiban, used NodeIP:NodePort, example: 172.16.20.77:31380/kibana
Istio-gateway-svc:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  name: istio-ingressgateway
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.109.142.5
  ports:
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 31380
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
-----
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  type: NodePort

Comment: Could you share you new VirtualService?